# How can I get the text to center in my scrollable UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, uilabel

The scrollable label works fine, but for some reason I cant get the text in the UILabel to center in the UIScrollView, it always stays left aligned. Here is an image of what I am talking about, and my code. (P.S. the UILabel is a subview of the UIScrollView, and the UIScrollView is a subview of the UITableViewCell.

[image]

```
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/21.5, 25, cell.frame.size.width - 40 , 20)];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [cell addSubview:scrollView];

    scrollLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    scrollLabel.text = secondaryLabel.text;
    scrollLabel.font = secondaryLabel.font;
    scrollLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    scrollLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    scrollLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    scrollLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [scrollLabel sizeToFit];
    [scrollView addSubview:scrollLabel];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollLabel.frame.size.width, 20);
```

Comment: Can you remove this line `[scrollLabel sizeToFit];`, and see what happen?

Comment: @anhtu I tried that and now it doesn't scroll anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you written for UILabel is pretty much right and the center  TextAlignment is there but the problem is you need to pass the right X & Y for UILabel Frame's. For now they are getting set to 0-0 and are adding on the Scrollview's starting frame. This might can solve your problem.